Tournament of Towns 2012 Spring Senior O5
This is a question from 2012 Tournament of Towns Spring Senior O5.
In an $8 \times 8$ chessboard, the rows are numbers from 1 to 8 and the columns are labelled from a to h. In a two-player game on this chessboard, the first player has a White Rook which starts on the square b2, and the second player has a Black Rook which starts on the square c4. The two players take turns moving their rooks. In each move, a rook lands on another square in the same row or the same column as its starting square. However, that square cannot be under attack by the other rook, and cannot have been landed on before by either rook. The player without a move loses the game. Which player has a winning strategy?
I tried to use symmetry (black mirrors white) but then there are instances where such a move is illegal (square already occupied before). I also tried to solve small cases (3x3 squares and 4x4 squares), it seems like black can win the game, but I’m not sure how to prove it.
Any hints are greatly appreciated, thank you.

Hint: "Symmetry", suitably applied, works. Because we're only moving in rows and columns (instead of diagonals), each row (resp column) is symmetric with any other row (resp column). So you just have to pick a symmetry, and exploit it:
Pair up the rows and columns separately, so that the square $B2$ corresponds to $C4$.
EG Take $(B, C), (A, D), (E, F), (G, H)$ and $(2, 4), (1, 3), (5, 6), (7, 8)$.
Let this be represented by $f$, so $f(B2) = C4$, and $f^2(x) = x$.
Now, show that Player 2 can mirror Player 1's move. Namely that if Player 1 moves from $x$ to $y$, show that

 1. $f(x)$ and $f(y)$ are in the same row or column because $x$ and $y$ are in the same row or column.
 2. $f(y)$ is not under attack by $y$, because they are in distinct rows and columns.
 3. $f(y)$ has not been previously occupied, because $y$ has not been previously occupied.

Thus, Player 2 can move from $f(x)$ to $f(y)$.
As it turns out, we could even allow Player 1 to move to a position that is under attack by Player 2.
Since the game is finite, hence player 2 always wins.
